# What is the difference between .contains(target) & target.contains()

Tags: javascript

I am catching a click and according to click close the menu :

To catch the click the code I tried is :

```
function someFnc(e){
let currentTarget = menuContain.contains(e.target);
   if(!currentTarget){
        document.body.style.color = "red";
    } else {
        document.body.style.color = "blue";
    }
}
```

Other code I tried is :

```
function someFnc(e){
   if(e.target.contains(menuContain)){
        document.body.style.color = "red";
    } else {
        document.body.style.color = "blue";
    }
}
```

Both works the same can anyone tell the reason because I am using same function `.contains`.
One is checking click is inside menu or  not and in other menu is catching click inside it or not

```js
let menuToggleCheck = document.getElementById("menuTogglerCheckbox");
let menuFixBg = document.getElementById("menuFix");
let menu = document.getElementById("menuToggler");
menuToggleCheck.addEventListener('click', menuTogglerBackground)

function menuTogglerBackground() {
  if (menuToggleCheck.checked) {
    menuFixBg.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(126, 125, 125, 0.5)";
    menuFixBg.style.width = "100vw";
    menuFixBg.style.height = "100vh";
  } else {
    menuFixBg.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    menuFixBg.style.width = "0vw"
    menuFixBg.style.height = "0vh"
  }
}

let menuContain = document.getElementById("menuContainer");
menuFixBg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let currentTarget = menuContain.contains(e.target);
  // e.target.contains(menuContain)
  if (!currentTarget) {
    document.body.style.color = "red";
    menuToggleCheck.checked = false;
    menuTogglerBackground();
  } else {
    document.body.style.color = "blue";
  }

})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#menuFix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

#menuContainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#menuToggler {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
  height: 80px;
  /* left: -100px; */
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggler input {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 7px;
  left: 21px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menuBarCircle {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#menuToggler span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 3px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: black;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: 1;
}

#menuToggler span:nth-child(1) {
  background: brown;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

#menuToggler span:nth-child(3) {
  background: brown;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

#menuToggler input:checked~.menuBarCircle span {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

#menuToggler input:checked~.menuBarCircle span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px, -1px);
}

#menuToggler input:checked~.menuBarCircle span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 1px);
}

#menuToggler input:checked~.menuBarCircle span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 90px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: white;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  /* z-index: -1; */
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: 0.5s width;
}

#menu a {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

#menu a li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#menu a:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 155, 155);
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 155, 155);
}

#menuToggler input:checked~#menu {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  transform: translate(0%, 0);
}

#menuToggler input:checked~#menu a {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuFix">
  <div id="menuContainer">
    <div id="menuToggler">
      <input type="checkbox" id="menuTogglerCheckbox" />
      <div class="menuBarCircle">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>

      <ul id="menu">
        <a href="#">
          <li>Home</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Settings</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>About Us</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Help</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>Hello World I am with you this is the grace of God to be with you</div>
```

Comment: What is `menuContain`? But obviously in one case the first element contains the second, in the other case the containment is the other way round.

Comment: @Bergi `menuContain` is side bar menu . Is both use are valid and will catch the clicks , if it is inside or outside menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although both could have the same effect depending on the HTML structure, they both do not work the same.
And in your provided example, they both do not always have the same result.

`firstNode.contains( secondNode )` checks to see if `secondNode` is a descendant of `firstNode` and returns this as a boolean value.
It will also return true if a node performs this check on itself; this `firstNode.contains( firstNode )` will equate to true.

```
function someFnc(e){
let currentTarget = menuContain.contains(e.target);
   if(!currentTarget){
        document.body.style.color = "red";
    } else {
        document.body.style.color = "blue";
    }
}
```

In the above example, currentTarget holds the answer to the question; "Is `e.target` a descendant of `menuContain`".

```
function someFnc(e){
   if(e.target.contains(menuContain)){
        document.body.style.color = "red";
    } else {
        document.body.style.color = "blue";
    }
}
```

In this above code block, you check to see if `menuContain` is a descendant of `e.target`.

`e.target` being the node on which the event was dispatched, or in your code's case, the node that was clicked on.

You can find more information on what .contains() does on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains), and more information on what event.target is on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

As for why both appear to work the same on your current code ( but remember, they don't ), well...

```
    let menuContain = document.getElementById("menuContainer");
    menuFixBg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        let currentTarget = menuContain.contains(e.target);
        // e.target.contains(menuContain)
        if (!currentTarget) {
            document.body.style.color = "red";
            menuToggleCheck.checked = false;
            menuTogglerBackground();
        } else {
            document.body.style.color = "blue";
        }
    })
```

In the above code, in your current HTML structure, #menuContainer occupies all of #menuFix's space, so any click event dispatched from #menuFix will come from either #menuContainer or one of it's descendants.

Because `e.target` will always either be #menuContainer or one of it's descendants, `let currentTarget = menuContain.contains(e.target);` will always be `true`.

Meaning that the font color will turn to blue in any case, with the above code.

In the case of using `if ( e.target.contains(menuContain) ) {`, this will be different.
If the click event is dispatched from #menuContainer, the if statement will equate to `true`, but if it's dispatched from one of its descendants, it will equate to `false`.
This is because descendants of #menuContainer won't contain #menuContainer.

Meaning, depending on where you click, the font will either be red or blue. I would suggest trying out Inspect Element in a browser that supports it and hovering over #menuContainer and its descendants in the Elements list to see what element occupies what space as this will be highlighted on the page.

See the below snippet as an example of how `if ( e.target.contains(menuContain) ) {` will have differing results depending on where you click.

Clicking near the circle will dispatch a click event from #menuToggler or one of its descendants, meaning the if statement will equate to false and the text will be blue.

Clicking further down, away from the circle, will dispatch a click event from #menuContainer, meaning the if statement will equate to true and the text will be red.

```js
let menuToggleCheck = document.getElementById("menuTogglerCheckbox");
let menuFixBg = document.getElementById("menuFix");
let menu = document.getElementById("menuToggler");
menuToggleCheck.addEventListener('click', menuTogglerBackground)

function menuTogglerBackground() {
  if (menuToggleCheck.checked) {
    menuFixBg.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(126, 125, 125, 0.5)";
    menuFixBg.style.width = "100vw";
    menuFixBg.style.height = "100vh";
  } else {
    menuFixBg.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    menuFixBg.style.width = "0vw"
    menuFixBg.style.height = "0vh"
  }
}

let menuContain = document.getElementById("menuContainer");
menuFixBg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    if ( e.target.contains(menuContain) ) {
        // #menuContainer was a descendant of the Clicked Element
        // Or the Clicked Element actually was #menuContainer
        document.body.style.color = "red";
        menuToggleCheck.checked = false;
        menuTogglerBackground();
    } else {
        // #menuContainer was not a descendant of the Clicked Element
        document.body.style.color = "blue";
    }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#menuFix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

#menuContainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#menuToggler {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
  height: 80px;
  /* left: -100px; */
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggler input {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 7px;
  left: 21px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menuBarCircle {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#menuToggler span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 3px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: black;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: 1;
}

#menuToggler span:nth-child(1) {
  background: brown;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

#menuToggler span:nth-child(3) {
  background: brown;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

#menuToggler input:checked~.menuBarCircle span {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

#menuToggler input:checked~.menuBarCircle span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px, -1px);
}

#menuToggler input:checked~.menuBarCircle span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 1px);
}

#menuToggler input:checked~.menuBarCircle span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 90px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: white;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  /* z-index: -1; */
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: 0.5s width;
}

#menu a {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

#menu a li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#menu a:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 155, 155);
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 155, 155);
}

#menuToggler input:checked~#menu {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  transform: translate(0%, 0);
}

#menuToggler input:checked~#menu a {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuFix">
  <div id="menuContainer">
    <div id="menuToggler">
      <input type="checkbox" id="menuTogglerCheckbox" />
      <div class="menuBarCircle">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>

      <ul id="menu">
        <a href="#">
          <li>Home</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Settings</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>About Us</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Help</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>Hello World I am with you this is the grace of God to be with you</div>
```

As a reply to your comment, here is a snippet where the menu will close if the user clicks inside the menu.
And some additional comments.

```js
let menuToggleCheck = document.getElementById("menuTogglerCheckbox");
let menuFixBg = document.getElementById("menuFix");
let menu = document.getElementById("menuToggler");
menuToggleCheck.addEventListener('click', menuTogglerBackground)

function menuTogglerBackground() {
  if (menuToggleCheck.checked) {
    menuFixBg.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(126, 125, 125, 0.5)";
    menuFixBg.style.width = "100vw";
    menuFixBg.style.height = "100vh";
  } else {
    menuFixBg.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    menuFixBg.style.width = "0vw"
    menuFixBg.style.height = "0vh"
  }
}

let menuContain = document.getElementById("menuContainer");
menuFixBg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    if ( e.target.id === "menuTogglerCheckbox" ) {
        // The User clicked on the Menu Toggle Box, which will have opened or closed the menu already, so do nothing
        return true;
    }
    // Check to see if the Click Target is inside the Menu Container
    let currentTarget = menuContain.contains(e.target);

    if ( currentTarget ) {
        // The user clicked inside the Menu Container
        document.body.style.color = "red";
        // Close the menu
        menuToggleCheck.checked = false;
        menuTogglerBackground();
    } else {
        // The user clicked outside the Menu Container
        document.body.style.color = "blue";
        // Maybe also close the menu?
        //menuToggleCheck.checked = false;
        //menuTogglerBackground();
    }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#menuFix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

#menuContainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#menuToggler {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
  height: 80px;
  /* left: -100px; */
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggler input {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 7px;
  left: 21px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menuBarCircle {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#menuToggler span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 3px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: black;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: 1;
}

#menuToggler span:nth-child(1) {
  background: brown;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

#menuToggler span:nth-child(3) {
  background: brown;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

#menuToggler input:checked~.menuBarCircle span {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

#menuToggler input:checked~.menuBarCircle span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px, -1px);
}

#menuToggler input:checked~.menuBarCircle span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 1px);
}

#menuToggler input:checked~.menuBarCircle span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 90px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: white;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  /* z-index: -1; */
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: 0.5s width;
}

#menu a {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

#menu a li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#menu a:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 155, 155);
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 155, 155);
}

#menuToggler input:checked~#menu {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  transform: translate(0%, 0);
}

#menuToggler input:checked~#menu a {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuFix">
  <div id="menuContainer">
    <div id="menuToggler">
      <input type="checkbox" id="menuTogglerCheckbox" />
      <div class="menuBarCircle">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>

      <ul id="menu">
        <a href="#">
          <li>Home</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Settings</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>About Us</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Help</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>Hello World I am with you this is the grace of God to be with you</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explanation (+1) . But as you said `menu.contains(e.target)` will always be true than why don't it close the `menu` when clicked on one of the links , And which is better approach

Comment: About your snippet, ```let currentTarget = menuContain.contains(e.target);``` will always be true.  But your following if statement executes the top block when ```currentTarget``` is false because of the ! you have in there. ```if ( !true ) {``` basically means ``ìf ( true === false ) {```, which it doesn't, so the if statement jumps to the ```} else {``` block. But, even with this if statement reversed, you will run into a different problem where clicking on #menuTogglerCheckbox will open the menu and the subsequent click event from #menuFix will close it. See the bottom of my updated answer.